# How do you say "three times a week" in Latin?

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

How do you say "three times a week" in Latin?

For context, I want to say that I swim three times a week.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your questions solved by clicking the arrow whichever response you feel answers your question best. That way, people won't think you're unsatisfied with the answers. (I see there are three open questions.) Let me know if you have any questions on how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

In medicine, taking a pill twice per day is *bis in diē*.

So on this model, three times per week would be *ter in hebdomade*.

(If you want to use the later word for "week" rather than the earlier/fancier one, that would be *ter in septimānā*.)

Answer (score 4):

*hebdomas,* or *hebdomada* are late Latin for 'a week.'

'Each and every week' is *Singulis hebdomadis.*

Once, twice, three times, four times (in Latin) are
*semel, bis, ter, quater.*  (like any other adverb, place it near to the verb)

After that it becomes more regular:

*quotiens* how many times; *totiens* so many times.

5x *quinquiens;* 6x *sexiens;* 7x *septiens.*

Answer (score 3):

"Three times" is *ter*, but there are some options to saying "per week".
The other answers have some suggestions, but mine is *quaque septimana* or *quaque hebdomade*, meaning "every week".
So I would say:

> Nato ter quaque septimana/hebdomade.
>   I swim thrice every week.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my answer to this question: [Is there a difference between septimana and hebdomas?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/812/is-there-a-difference-between-septimana-and-hebdomas) there is no word for "week" in Classical Latin. The other answers to your question refer to the usage of Christian authors only. So, in Classical Latin, the answer to the question would be, "it isn't possible".

Comment: Is this an actual answer to the question? The OP seems not to be restricting him/herself to Classical Latin.